# Not displaying font on mac safari when added custom font-family and apply to body

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

View on Mac Safari:

[image: view on mac safari]

View on Windows Chrome:

[image: view on windows chrome]

Here is the css stye

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Gotham HTF Light;
    src: url(gothamlight.ttf) format("truetype");
    src: url(gotham-black.otf) format("otf");}
@font-face {
    font-family: Gotham HTF Book;
    src: url(gothambook.ttf) format("truetype");
    src: url(gotham-black.otf) format("otf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Gotham HTF Medium;
    src: url(gothammedium.ttf) format("truetype");
    src: url(gotham-black.otf) format("otf");
}


html, body {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
body{        
    font-weight:normal;
} 
*{
    font-family:'Gotham HTF Light';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
input, select, textarea, button,label{
    font-family:inherit; 
}
```

> How can resolve this problem if I removed the font-family:'Gotham HTF
>   Light'; then its working fine but whe I apply custom font it dont work
>   on form fields.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and turns out the .ttf file that I was using was defective. I did not realize that right away, because in chrome worked.

To solve the problem I just downloaded other .ttf file (that worked on Safari).

Answer (score 0):

Uses all font formats to support all browsers (including Safari). Try This

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham HTF Light';
    src: url((gothammedium.eot);/* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url((gothammedium.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),/* IE6-IE8 */       
         url(gothammedium.woff2) format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
         url(gothammedium.woff) format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
         url(gothammedium.ttf) format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url(gothammedium.svg) format('svg');/* Legacy iOS */
}
```